# How do i write the html and php code that sends form filled on my website to my email?

Tags: php, html, web

I wrote HTML and PHP that sends an email using a form, but the code is not working. I am getting an error message on submit, "This page isn’t working [www.adurotoluwasupport.org](http://www.adurotoluwasupport.org) is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500".

I'm not sure what I did wrong.

**HTML**

```
<div style="padding:20px" class="col-sm-7">
  <h2>Become a Volunteer</h2> <br>
  <form id="fcf-form-id" class="fcf-form-class" method="post" action="volunteer.php">
    <div class="row cont-row">
      <div class="col-sm-3"><label for="Position">Volunteer Position </label><span>:</span></div>
      <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" id="Position" placeholder="Tell us what you are volunteering for" name="Position" class="form-control input-sm" required></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row cont-row">
      <div class="col-sm-3"><label for="Name">Full Name </label><span>:</span></div>
      <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" id="Name" placeholder="Enter Name" name="Name" class="form-control input-sm" pattern=[A-Z\sa-z]{4,30} required></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row cont-row">
      <div class="col-sm-3"><label for="Email">Email Address </label><span>:</span></div>
      <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="email" id="Email" name="Email" placeholder="Enter Email Address" class="form-control input-sm" required></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row cont-row">
      <div class="col-sm-3"><label for="Number">Mobile Number</label><span>:</span></div>
      <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="tel" id="Number" name="Number" placeholder="Enter Mobile Number" class="form-control input-sm" required></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row cont-row">
      <div class="col-sm-3"><label for="Address">Address </label><span>:</span></div>
      <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" id="Address" placeholder="Your residential address" name="Address" class="form-control input-sm" required></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row cont-row">
      <div class="col-sm-3"><label for="State">Enter State </label><span>:</span></div>
      <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" id="State" name="State" placeholder="Your State of Residence" class="form-control input-sm" required></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row cont-row">
      <div class="col-sm-3"><label for="Country">Enter Country</label><span>:</span></div>
      <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" id="Country" name="Country" placeholder="Your Country of Residence" class="form-control input-sm" required></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row cont-row">
      <div class="col-sm-3"><label for="Occupation">Occupation </label><span>:</span></div>
      <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" id="Occupation" placeholder="Enter Occupation" name="Occupation" class="form-control input-sm" required></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row cont-row">
      <div class="col-sm-3"><label for="Experience">Volunteer Xpernce.</label><span>:</span></div>
      <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" id="Experience" name="Experience" placeholder="Your previous volunteer experience / Optional " class="form-control input-sm"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row cont-row">
      <div class="col-sm-3"><label for="Languages">Languages Spoken</label><span>:</span></div>
      <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" id="Languages" name="Languages" placeholder="Tell us the language(s) you speak fluently" class="form-control input-sm" required></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row cont-row">
      <div class="col-sm-3"><label for="Gender">Gender</label><span>:</span></div>
      <div class="col-sm-8"><select id="Gender" name="Gender" class="form-control input-sm" required>
          <option Value="">Select your Gender</option>
          <option value="male">Male</option>
          <option value="female">Female</option>
          <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row cont-row">
      <div class="col-sm-3"><label for="Dob">Date of Birth</label><span>:</span></div>
      <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="date" id="Dob" name="Dob" placeholder="Enter your Date of Birth" class="form-control input-sm" required></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row cont-row">
      <div class="col-sm-3"><label for="Info">Other information</label><span>:</span></div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <textarea rows="5" id="Info" placeholder="Enter other information that enable us make a good match" class="form-control input-sm"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top:10px;" class="row">
      <div style="padding-top:10px;" class="col-sm-3"><label></label></div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <button type="submit" id="fcf-button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['Email'])) {
    
        // EDIT THE FOLLOWING TWO LINES:
        $email_to = "example@gmail.com";
        $email_subject = "Volunteer form submissions";
    
        function problem($error)
        {
            echo "We're sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
            echo "These errors appear below.<br><br>";
            echo $error . "<br><br>";
            echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br><br>";
            die();
        }
    
        // validation expected data exists
        if (
            !isset($_POST['Position']) ||
            !isset($_POST['Name']) ||
            !isset($_POST['Email']) ||
            !isset($_POST['Number']) ||
            !isset($_POST['Address']) ||
            !isset($_POST['State']) ||
            !isset($_POST['Country']) ||
            !isset($_POST['Occupation']) ||
            !isset($_POST['Experience']) ||
            !isset($_POST['Languages']) ||
            !isset($_POST['Gender']) ||
            !isset($_POST['Dob']) ||
            !isset($_POST['Info'])
        ) {
            problem('We're sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
        }
        $position = $_POST['Position']; // required
        $name = $_POST['Name']; // required
        $email = $_POST['Email']; // required
        $number = $_POST['Number']; // required
        $address = $_POST['Address']; // required
        $state = $_POST['State']; // required
        $country = $_POST['Country']; // required
        $occupation = $_POST['Occupation']; // required
        $experience = $_POST['Experience']; // 
        $languages = $_POST['Languages']; // required
        $gender = $_POST['Gender']; // required
        $dob = $_POST['Dob']; // required
        $info = $_POST['Info']; //
        $error_message = "";
        $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
    
        if (!preg_match($email_exp, $email)) {
            $error_message .= 'The Email address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br>';
        }
    
        $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
    
        if (!preg_match($string_exp, $name)) {
            $error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br>';
        }
    
        if (strlen($message) < 2) {
            $error_message .= 'The Message you entered do not appear to be valid.<br>';
        }
    
        if (strlen($error_message) > 0) {
            problem($error_message);
        }
    
        $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";
    
        function clean_string($string)
        {
            $bad = array("content-type", "bcc:", "to:", "cc:", "href");
            return str_replace($bad, "", $string);
        }
    
        $email_message .= "Position: " . clean_string($position) . "\n";
        $email_message .= "Name: " . clean_string($name) . "\n";
        $email_message .= "Email: " . clean_string($email) . "\n";
        $email_message .= "Number: " . clean_string($number) . "\n";
        $email_message .= "Address: " . clean_string($address) . "\n";
        $email_message .= "State: " . clean_string($state) . "\n";
        $email_message .= "Country: " . clean_string($country) . "\n";
        $email_message .= "Occupation: " . clean_string($occupation) . "\n";
        $email_message .= "Experience: " . clean_string($experience) . "\n";
        $email_message .= "Languages: " . clean_string($languages) . "\n";
        $email_message .= "Gender: " . clean_string($gender) . "\n";
        $email_message .= "Dob: " . clean_string($dob) . "\n";
        $email_message .= "Info: " . clean_string($info) . "\n";
    
        // create email headers
        $headers = 'From: ' . $email . "\r\n" .
            'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
        @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
    ?>
    
        <!-- INCLUDE YOUR SUCCESS MESSAGE BELOW -->
    
        Thanks for volunteering. We'll get back to you soon.
    
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and format the php code in a proper way.

Comment: Welcome. Please check your question, it looks pretty chaotic, especially for the PHP code part. [edit] it and make yourself comfortable with the interface to format it. Additionally check the [help] on how you can further improve your question, e.g. how it can benefit from a minimal example to reproduce.

Comment: i have edited the question and formatted the php code in a proper way

Comment: Ah, the important part: "HTTP ERROR 500": you have to check the PHP error log (could be in the webservers error log) for PHP fatal errors. That should lead you to the concrete PHP error message. Rule of thumb: error 500 = invitation to look into the error log.

Comment: @FlashThunder: regarding your comment: `"\"` is the escape character, not `"/"`.

Answer (score 1):

I think I see where your problem is:

```
problem("We're sorry ....")
```

Make sure you use the correct **"" or ''**.

[image]

Comment: yupp, but op should learn how to use error log or how to write all errors directly

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<div style="padding:20px" class="col-sm-7">
    <h2>Become a Volunteer</h2>
    <br>
    <form id="fcf-form-id" class="fcf-form-class" method="post" action="volunteer.php">
        <div class="row cont-row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label for="Position">Volunteer Position </label><span>:</span></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" id="Position" placeholder="Tell us what you are volunteering for" name="Position" class="form-control input-sm" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row cont-row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label for="Name">Full Name </label><span>:</span></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" id="Name" placeholder="Enter Name" name="Name" class="form-control input-sm" pattern=[A-Z\sa-z]{4,30} required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row cont-row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label for="Email">Email Address </label><span>:</span></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="email" id="Email" name="Email" placeholder="Enter Email Address" class="form-control input-sm" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row cont-row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label for="Number">Mobile Number</label><span>:</span></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="tel" id="Number" name="Number" placeholder="Enter Mobile Number" class="form-control input-sm" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row cont-row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label for="Address">Address </label><span>:</span></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" id="Address" placeholder="Your residential address" name="Address" class="form-control input-sm" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row cont-row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label for="State">Enter State </label><span>:</span></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" id="State" name="State" placeholder="Your State of Residence" class="form-control input-sm" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row cont-row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label for="Country">Enter Country</label><span>:</span></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" id="Country" name="Country" placeholder="Your Country of Residence" class="form-control input-sm" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row cont-row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label for="Occupation">Occupation </label><span>:</span></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" id="Occupation" placeholder="Enter Occupation" name="Occupation" class="form-control input-sm" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row cont-row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label for="Experience">Volunteer Xpernce.</label><span>:</span></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" id="Experience" name="Experience" placeholder="Your previous volunteer experience / Optional " class="form-control input-sm">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row cont-row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label for="Languages">Languages Spoken</label><span>:</span></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" id="Languages" name="Languages" placeholder="Tell us the language(s) you speak fluently" class="form-control input-sm" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row cont-row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label for="Gender">Gender</label><span>:</span></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <select id="Gender" name="Gender" class="form-control input-sm" required>
                    <option Value="">Select your Gender</option>
                    <option value="male">Male</option>
                    <option value="female">Female</option>
                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row cont-row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label for="Dob">Date of Birth</label><span>:</span></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="date" id="Dob" name="Dob" placeholder="Enter your Date of Birth" class="form-control input-sm" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row cont-row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label for="Info">Other information</label><span>:</span></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <textarea rows="5" id="Info" placeholder="Enter other information that enable us make a good match" class="form-control input-sm"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top:10px;" class="row">
            <div style="padding-top:10px;" class="col-sm-3">
                <label></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <button type="submit" id="fcf-button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

and create php file
volunteer.php

```
<?php var_dump($_POST) ?>
```

You will see all posts inside var_dump

Comment: If you've got clarification questions to _actually_ answer the question, use comments. If you don't have enough reputation to comment yet, use voting (e.g. a programming question that can't be answered is not helpful, vote it down). If you're asking yourself why that is this way (and why it is good this way), please consult the [help].

Comment: i have tried <?php var_dump($_POST) ?>, i am getting the same error message "This page isn’t workingwww.adurotoluwasupport.org is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500"

Comment: According to the check, the issue is related to the following error:
PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /home/aduroggn/public_html/volunteer.php on line 5